# Unkown attribute in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

In my models/lead_billing.rb, I have the following:

```
attr_accessible :ticket_update_type
```

ticket_update_type is NOT in the MySQL table, and I am using in the submission form as a hidden field.

This is the submission form (slim):

```
= form_for(LeadBilling.new, url: lead_billing_path) do |f|
  .form-horizontal-column.customer-info
    .form-group
      = f.label :pre_tax_total
      = f.text_field :pre_tax_total, maxlength: 50
      = f.error_message :pre_tax_total
    .form-group
      = f.label :post_tax_total
      = f.text_field :post_tax_total, maxlength: 50
      = f.error_message :post_tax_total
    .form-group
      = f.hidden_field :ticket_update_type, value: "save_lead_billing"
  .form-horizontal-column.customer-info
    .actions = f.submit 'Save Lead Billing Details'
.clear
```

When I fill it, and click on the submit button, I get the "something went wrong" screen. Looking through the log file, I see the following error message:

```
unknown attribute: ticket_update_type from user
```

With the additional details:

```
/home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:88:in `block in assign_attributes'
/home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
/home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
/home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `initialize'
/home/app/app/controllers/admin/lead_billings_controller.rb:42:in `new'
/home/app/app/controllers/admin/lead_billings_controller.rb:42:in `create'
```

So, it's an initialization issue? But I already declared it in the lead_billing model.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `ticket_update_type` isn't part of LeadBilling model, then you should not tie it with that model in your form, instead of:

```
= f.hidden_field :ticket_update_type, value: "save_lead_billing"
```

you have to define it as a `hidden_field_tag`:

```
= hidden_field_tag :ticket_update_type, value: "save_lead_billing"
```

now, in your controller you can ask for it via `params[:ticket_update_type]` and you don't have to add any unnecessary accessors to LeadBilling model

Answer (score 1):

try

```
attr_accessor(:ticket_update_type)
```

Comment: Why the paranthesis?

Comment: they are not needed, but i prefer them, because i think they make it easier to read

Comment: mainly it's `accessor` not `accessible`

Comment: OK, now I am getting: No route matches lead_billings, and I am also getting a warning: WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: ticket_update_type

Comment: and this is what I have in my routes.rb: post '/lead_billings' => 'lead_billings#create', as: 'lead_billing'

Comment: see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit